# How to get area of pixels of a Mat Image

Tags: java, opencv

I am new to using Opencv with Java. I have a `Mat` image and I am trying to read pixels in a specific area so then I later can loop through that area and determine the HSV of that I am trying to use a `CvRect` to get the coordinates and size of region I want of the image. How would I get that region of the image?

```
Mat firstImage = Imgcodecs.imread("firstImage.png");
    CvRect topL = new CvRect(firstImage.get(160, 120, 30, 30));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it: read the pixels one by one, or get all the pixels in a rectangle into java for the whole image, and then work with the larger array.  Which one is best probably depends on how large the rect is.  The code below gets the specified rect part of the image into a Java array first.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;

public class OpenCVThing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String opencvpath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\lib\\";
        System.load(opencvpath + Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME + ".dll");
        // Get the whole rect into smallImg
        Mat firstImage = Highgui.imread("capture.png");
        System.out.println("total pxels:" + firstImage.total());
        // We are getting a column 30 high and 30 wide
        int width = 30;
        int height = 30;
        Rect roi = new Rect(120, 160, width, height);
        Mat smallImg = new Mat(firstImage, roi);
        int channels = smallImg.channels();
        System.out.println("small pixels:" + smallImg.total());
        System.out.println("channels:" + smallImg.channels());
        int totalBytes = (int)(smallImg.total() * smallImg.channels());
        byte buff[] = new byte[totalBytes];
        smallImg.get(0, 0, buff);

        // assuming it's of CV_8UC3 == BGR, 3 byte/pixel
        // Effectively assuming channels = 3
        for (int i=0; i< height; i++)
        {
            // stride is the number of bytes in a row of smallImg
            int stride = channels * width;
            for (int j=0; j<stride; j+=channels)
            {
                int b = buff[(i * stride) + j];
                int g = buff[(i * stride) + j + 1]; 
                int r = buff[(i * stride) + j + 2];
                float[] hsv = new float[3];
                Color.RGBtoHSB(r,g,b,hsv);
                // Do something with the hsv.
                System.out.println("hsv: " + hsv[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE 1**: In this case, each byte in the buff represents a third of a pixel, because I have assumed the format is CV_8UC3.

Code was tested on a screen capture of this answer with the following output:

```
total pxels:179305
small pixels:900
channels:3
hsv: 0.5833333
hsv: 0.5833333
hsv: 0.5833333
hsv: 0.5833333
hsv: 0.5833333

etc ...
```

See [this page](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5/how-to-get-and-modify-the-pixel-of-mat-in-java/) and the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html) for a little more detail

Comment: The `CvRect tolL = new CvRect(firstImage.get(160,120,30,30));` doesn't actually work in getting the image the CvRect can't take that as an argument, I used it in my question to demonstrate that I wanted to get that region of that image.

Comment: The image I get I am not sure what `CV type` the image I am using is, I get the image from a frame of a video capture and then try to get the values of that image. This is what it is `mat2Img.getImage(mat2Img.mat);` it is An Object of Mat2Image.

Comment: firstImage.type(); will return an int that represents one of the types at http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-type Not sure how to convert the number in Java though.

Comment: I can use a jpg I have no problem using either I will work with that. Would it be better if I did that?

Comment: Regardless of file type, you need to know what opencv format the image is so you can do the correct calculation for the HSV on the pixel data so you might as well find out what it is.

Comment: I did modify my code to what you suggested in your answer but I am getting an exception now. it has to do with some assumption made in your answer. Btw the number returned by the `firstImage.type()` was 16.

Comment: Oh I see, it makes more sense now, a question I have is why multiply by 40 * 3? and what would Stride mean in this sense?

Comment: Thank you so much,  I will modify it to work with what I have currently but I tested it out and it does work, I really appreciate it. I have one question, how did you learn this, I know I will hit another roadblock eventually and since I am not familiar with OpenCV as much I may not be sure what to do.